# impala SQL timediff

Tags: sql, datetime, impala

I have a field value like "2014-08-12 13:17:00" this is in string in database.
if i have two field values like this i.e start time & end time(2 different database fields)

I'm trying to find difference in minutes from two fields.

I was able to convert from string to timestamp but I'm not sure how do I find difference in minutes,tried subtracting though or may be I'm something wrong in syntax.

An pointers?

Comment: you can use the `datediff` function

Comment: still struggling to get syntax right!!

Comment: please post the code you wrote